# SMS Integration doesn't work?

Tags: php

I Integrate to SMS gateway using php, SMS send local server xampp fine, but cannot send main server apache linux server, Please Help me any one?

This is my intergrate code:-

```
$contact_no = "1234567890";
$message = "Congradulations.Mr.Name.Your Registration successfull.User ID : Name & Password : 12345. Thankyou";
$message = urlencode($message);
$url = 'http://domain.co.in/api/sendsms.php?user=user_id&apikey=KEY&mobile='.$contact_no.'&message='.$message.'&senderid=SENDERID&type=txt';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
echo $xml;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No Error. Get to Empty Screen

Comment: Which sms gateway provider are you using?

Comment: http://smshorizon.co.in

Comment: Did you enable xml extension of php on your server?

Comment: How to enable xml extension

Comment: allow_url_fopen php setting could be disabled on the server. are you getting any warnings? you can use `php_info();` to verify this